# How to correctly Link lua 5.3 with CodeBlocks(C++)

Tags: c++, lua, compiler-errors, codeblocks, mingw32

I am creating a project using SDL2 and Lua, however I am having linking issues with the compiler.  I've merged the lua libary, include, and dlls with that of SDL to create a common link, but the compiler refuses to recognize "lua.h"

Additional Linker Options: -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -llua53

Code I am using to test:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
}

int main()
{
  lua_State *L = lua_open();
  lua_close(L);
  return 0;
}
```

If I am doing something incorrect or if I am missing anything crucial please let me know.

Comment: `lua.h` isn't a linker issue. It is a compiler issue. You need the appropriate `-I` flag pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where I would go to see about fixing that? (somewhat inexperienced with Codeblocks troubleshooting)

Comment: There should be an "Additional Compilation Options" or similar option I would expect. (Or something talking about CFLAGS/etc.)

Comment: My bad - It appears that I actually made a mistake in placement of my header files and upon correction it finally works. Many thanks